# Haskell: convert Day to UNIX timestamp

Tags: haskell, time, timestamp

How do I get the UNIX timestamp for "one week ago"? Currently I do:

```
import Data.Time
...
oneWeekAgo = toTimestamp . addDays (-7) <$> now
  where now = utctDay <$> getCurrentTime
        toTimestamp = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%s"
```

But this doesn't work because `formatTime` is returning an *empty* string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but you may want to modify `utctDay` and use `utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds` to convert `UTCTime` to a posix timestamp.

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX

oneWeekAgo = do now <- getCurrentTime
                let oneWeekAgo = now { utctDay = addDays (-7) $ utctDay now }
                return $ utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds oneWeekAgo
```

Or just subtracting the seconds would be fine too.

```
oneWeekAgo = ((subtract (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) . utcTimeToPOSIXSeconds) <$> getCurrentTime
```

Comment: The later is short and sweet, but can we get away with `7 * 24 * 60 * 60`? I like writing `-7` as it is immediately obvious what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I just came up with is to use `UTCTime day 0` to convert the day value back to time.

```
import Data.Time
...
oneWeekAgo = toTimestamp . toTime . addDays (-7) <$> now
  where now = utctDay <$> getCurrentTime
        toTimestamp = formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%s"
        toTime day = UTCTime day 0
```